# Can you get full paths from the pasteboard when drag and dropping?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I am supporting a drag-and-drop operation on an IKImageBrowserView. In my drag and drop destination delegate I accept NSFilenamesPboardType drops. The weird part is that the filepath strings I get back all start with "/Users/..." instead of "file://localhost/..." as I get when using an NSOpenPanel. When I convert these to NSURLs for use by the IKImageBrowserView to show images, it gets confused because it only understands full paths starting with "file://localhost/...". I can hack the prefix in, as I've done in the snippet below, but I was wondering if there was a programatic way to get full paths instead?

```
if ([[pasteboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType])
{
    NSData* data = [pasteboard dataForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
    if (data)
    {
        NSString* errorDescription;
        NSArray* filenames = [NSPropertyListSerialization
            propertyListFromData:data
            mutabilityOption:kCFPropertyListImmutable
            format:nil
            errorDescription:&errorDescription];

        for (id filename in filenames)
        {   
            NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost%@", filename]];

            NSLog(@"Adding URL: %@", url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a file URL from a full path, don't add `file://` prefix yourself. Just use

```
    NSURL* url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBGFBJ).

From the point of view of the operating system,

```
   /Users/myname/file.txt
```

is the full path of a file in the system. In a higher level API which also allows various network access, the local file is distinguished by putting `file://` protocol. 
Those pboard APIs predates the prevalent usage of URL in the API, that's why it returns paths as full paths, not as file URLs.